# Spring-Boot project log4j to log4j2 conversion Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I am upgrading my logging framework from log4j to log4j2. I have followed the steps from the apache guys [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).

1. I modified my log4j.xml to the new standards(especially for the Appenders)
2. Upgraded my gradle file to the new dependencies
3. Rebuilt my spring-boot packager project and deployed it

I am using these system properties when deploying my jar:

---

> java Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar application.jar

---

However, my application continues to run log4j and not log4j2. When setting the debug property `Dlog4j.debug` I can see that log4j is trying to find the xml,properties, etc, and then says

`No appenders could be found for logger. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.`

So somewhere I am picking up version 1.2?

The only reason I believe log4j2 is running is when I change the name of the log4j2.xml to log4j.xml, I get a log4j warning stating 
`log4j2.xml could not be found. Only displying error messages to the console.` Even though log4j spits out messages along with that.

Anyone come across something similar when switching from log4j and log4j2 and could provide some assistance?

Comment: How your dependencies in Gradle look like? There is one starter for Log4j2 (`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`) now and "potentially" you might have to exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` also (depending on the other dependencies, of course).

Comment: Yes, I have `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and have excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` I also have `org.apache.logging.log4j log4j-api`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for Gradle 3.2.1 and Spring Boot 1.4.2.

1. You have to import `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging`
2. Rename the `log4j.xml` to `log4j2.xml` and modify it accordingly (I think you already did that)
3. Either copy/include the `log4j2.xml` file inside `src/main/resources` or refer it by using the `-Dlogging.config` (not the `log4j.configurationFile` as you are using since it's a Spring Boot application)

In the end, your Gradle config file should look like (excerpt):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.0.RELEASE')
    classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE')
  }
}

plugins {
  // ...
}

//apply from: 'gradle/database.gradle'

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

configurations {
  all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
  //all*.exclude module: 'jboss-logging-annotations'
  //all*.exclude module: 'jboss-logging'
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.4.2.RELEASE")
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.5'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion '3.2.1'
}
```

...your Log4j 2.x config file should look like this (this only have the appender that logs into the console and the `DEBUG` level is only "activated" for this namespace/package `io.shido`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-pattern">%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} |- %highlight{%5p}{TRACE=blue, DEBUG=green, INFO=green, WARN=yellow, ERROR=red, FATAL=red} in %style{%C{1}:%L}{cyan} [%style{%t#${sys:PID}}{magenta}] - %m%n</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${log-pattern}" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <!-- Logger levels: ALL, TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF -->
  <Loggers>
    <AsyncLogger name="io.shido" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </AsyncLogger>

    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

...and if you don't have the `log4j2.xml` file inside `src/main/resources` so it will be picked by default, or if you need to specify a different one, use the `--logging.config` directive:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=default -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlogging.config assets/log4j2.xml
```

Comment: My log4j2.xml is within `src/main/resources`, when I use the command `-Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml` I get `Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` from a FileNotFoundException. I even tried using the `-Dlogging.config` to clarify the path and it still could not find the file

Comment: Should the output from log4j for a log4j2 configuration be `log4j:asdfasdfasf` or `log4j2:asdfasdfasdf`?

Comment: Don't use the `-Dlogging.config` directive for now, put the file inside `src/main/resources` and see what's going on, then try to tweak (aka "make it work") it with `-Dlogging.config`

Comment: The file is within `src/main/resources` and I tried running with & without the `-Dlogging.config`. I feel as if my project is running log4j and not log4j2 somehow and I am not catching it.

Comment: I also was able to get a warning that the log4j.dtd file was not found, so I think log4j2 is not even running.